# Dynamically render a react component with react routing, based on value given in url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Basically what I want to do is create a react portfolio project that contains and showcases all of my react projects. But I don't know how to render a project based on a url value.

What I mean is,

```
   <Route path='/projects/:projectName' component={Project}></Route>
```

I want to render a component based on the `:projectName` vakue.
Or maybe create a `Project` component that just renders the given project based on the url value. 
Is that even possible? I know I can use `match` to get the `:projectName` value, but how could I use it to render a component?

Answer (score 1):

There are few approaches
1. As mentioned above to let project component decide what should be rendered based on match.params

```
const routes = {
 'my-route1': <MyComponent1 />,
 'my-route2': <MyComponent2 />
}

const Project = props => {
  const { projectName } = props.match.params
  return routes[projectName] || <DefaultComponent />
}
```

2. You may define your own routes components who will decide which component to Render based on state. It is helpful when you need to create master pages or templates and do not want any dependencies on match inside other components.

```
    const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
      const func = props => (!!rest.isUserAllowedToNavigate()
        ? <Component {...props} />
        : (
          <Redirect to={
              {
                pathname: '/login',
                search: props.location.pathname !== '/' && queryStringComposer({
                  redirect_from: props.location.pathname || getQueryStringParam('redirect_from')
                })
              }
            }
          />
        )
      )
      return (<Route {...rest} render={func} />)
    }
    /* Connecting to redux */
    const PrivateRouteConnected = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PrivateRoute)
    /* Using as normal routes */
    <PrivateRouteConnected exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
```

Answer (score 0):

your `Project` component can handle the logic to render a different component based on the URL param.  For example:

```
const Project = props => {
  const { projectName } = props.match.params
  if (projectName === project1) {
    return <ProjectOne addProps={addProps} />
  }
  if (projectName === project2) {
    return <ProjectTwo />
  }
  return <DefaultProject />
}
```